# Make draggable elements(circle,rectangle like shapes) which can take input from HTML form

Tags: php, css, jquery-ui, yii2, forms

I am working on restaurant management web application in PHP.

In this application i want to  create floor plan layout of tables that means admin can drag and drop tables from the left side and create the layout of the restaurants on the right side and store the layout and  tables details in database.

I am using Yii2 framework.

For this i have created canvas tag which is draggable but how i can take input from the canvas?

My canvas tag :

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;" value="4"></canvas>
```

Jquery :

```
 $(function() {
        $( "#myCanvas" ).draggable();
    });
```

I have tried as above. I don't know weather i am on right way or not.

Please give some idea how can i do this draggable canvas input form Which saves the tables details to my database.

Answer (score 0):

You can define regions in your canvas, which have a boundaries. The simplest way to do that is to be aware of the rectangle/circle around your elements. By clicking into a given position, you will know about the x,y value and, if you know the inequality of your shapes, then you will be able to determine which shape(s) is/are containing the point you have clicked on. In our case, since you want to work with dragging, the events you will be interested about are:

- [ondragstart](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondragstart.asp)
- [ondragend](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondragend.asp)

At these events you will be able to find out what was the point where the drag has started and what was the point where the drag has ended, so, you will be able to determine which item in your initial canvas contains the point where the drag started and which point should be created your item at in your destination canvas. But it would be nice to make a graphical display of the dragging and for this purpose you could create a container which would be filled with an image that you need and move along with your cursor. You could achieve that by creating a movable container that would be visualized on ondragstart, moved on ondrag and hide on ondragend.